# Why won't this submit value to database?

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

**JS:**
The JS for client side validation of `email` field

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="src/js/validate.js"> </script> 
   <script type="text/javascript">
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
    });

    $().ready(function() {
        // validate alphaRegister form on keyup and submit
        $("#alphaRegister").validate({
            rules: {
                email: {
                    required: true,
                    email: true
                }
            },
            messages: {
                email: "*"
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

**HTML**
The form

```
    <form id="alphaRegister" action="src/php/newSubscriber.php" method="post">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="cemail" value="" class="required" />
        <div style="float:right; margin:0 5px 2px 0;"><input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="" /></div>
    </form>
```

When I enter a validname@adomain.com, it just says `submitted!!`

**PHP File**
The file handling the input of the html

```
 <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="myuser"; // Mysql username       
    $username2="root"; #localhost
$password="mypass"; // Mysql password  
    $password2=""; #localhost
$db_name="mydbname"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="mydbtblname"; // Table name

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username2", "$password2")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot connect to database");

/* Obliterate bad input */
$goodEmail = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

$sql= "INSERT INTO alphaSubscribers (alphaSEmAddr) VALUES('$goodEmail')";

$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid Email, please retry.');
}
else {
    header( 'Location: /index.php' ) ;
    echo "<meta HTTP-EQUIV='REFRESH' content='0; url=/index.php'>";
}

?>
```

Anyone see what Im doing wrong?

Comment: what error  you getting ? paste here

Comment: added post, it doesn't submit to database..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending the form via `GET` but test for the `POST` parameter. Change your form tag to

```
<form id="alphaRegister" action="src/php/newSubscriber.php" method="post">
```

Also remove the javascript `submitHandler`, otherwise the form might not get submitted at all:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); } // <= remove that line
});
```

Comment: So remove just this: `submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }` ?

Comment: yes, you can also remove the whole statement as it will be empty anyways.

Comment: How do I get it to output "Thanks" when a successful value was entered?

Answer (score 0):

Your form is using the `GET` method, while your back-end PHP code is handling it as `$_POST`

Your HTML method should be  `method="POST">`

Answer (score 0):

From [jquery docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate): Use submitHandler to implement your own form submit, eg. via Ajax.

Your submit handler validator prevents that for was submited in a regular way.

Remove this code and try again:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function() { alert("submitted!"); }
});
```